# Shortend array printing wrong result

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to create shorten the size of array to cerstaind number. I have a class

```
class Numbers{
public:
  Numbers(){
     max = 10;
     arr = new int[max];
     current = 0;
 }
private:
 int *arr;
 int max;
 int current;
}
```

What i simply want to do. If the array contains numbers (10) e.g

```
arr // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

and i call `.shorten(number)` method , it will shorten array to said number , so in 6 it would be

```
arr // 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I have created a method

```
void Numbers::shorten(int a ){
  int *tmp = new int[a];
  for( int i = 0; i < a; i++){
    tmp[i] = arr[i];  
  }
  max = a;
  delete[] arr;
  arr = tmp;
}
```

When i invoke this method , and print the array , the output should be `1 2 3 4 5 6` but instead it prints the same array with  first two numbers being some random numbers from memory. What causes this , how can i prevent this from happening?

printing function looks like this

```
void Numbers::PrintAll(){
  for( int i = 0; i < max ; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
  }
}
```

and declaring it as

```
Numbers one;
```

//I know i can use STL containers but i would like to do this with arrays.

Comment: That code won't compile, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you use this class, how you initialize the objects, how you use the functions and most importantly how you *print* the result.

Comment: Added it to the question.

Comment: Just looking at your code it seems like it should work, and I [can't replicate it](http://ideone.com/WnrunX) either. So the error is most likely in some code you don't show. Do you, perchance, pass the object by value to a function? Or return by value? What does your destructor do? What does copy-constructor do? You *do* have a copy-constructor?

Comment: Code works when I tested it

Answer (score 0):

You do not modify `max` in your `shorten` method, so `print` tries to print more numbers that are actually there.